# Authenticating Mac local users in Java

Tags: java, macos, authentication, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

I have used jcifs to authenticate Windows users (local as well as domain)

How do i authenticate Mac local users using Java code ?

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [libpam4j](https://github.com/kohsuke/libpam4j)

Here is a simple example with libpam4j:

```
UnixUser user = null;
try {
  user = new PAM("pam service").authenticate("username","password");
  // authentication success
} catch (PAMException ex){
  // authentication failed
}
```

The library is also available via maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
  <artifactId>libpam4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using [JPAM](http://jpam.sourceforge.net/). It does use some native code (which is provided), but it's simple to set up and ties straight into PAM, so it'll work on almost any *nix, including Mac OS X.